# Align projected 2d plot on 3dscatter grid in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I'm don't have much experience with python, only a basic course. I'm trying to create a scatter plot with 3 dimensions and 2d plot proyected on the faces of the plot area.

This is the [dataset](https://pastebin.com/KkeQvusS)

So far, I have this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    dataset = pd.read_csv("dummy.csv")

    x = dataset.das_avg
    y = dataset.thick_mm
    z = dataset.cool_rate_avg
    color = dataset.temp_mold


    fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10,5)) 
    ax = Axes3D(fig)

    ax.plot(x, z, 'r+', zdir='y', zs=0 ,marker= 'o', alpha=0.05)
    ax.plot(y, z, 'g+', zdir='x', zs=0, marker= 'o', alpha=0.05)
    ax.plot(x, y, 'y+', zdir='z', zs=0, marker= 'o', alpha=0.05)
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=20, c=color, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

    ax.set_xlabel('X') 
    ax.set_ylabel('Y') 
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')

    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.jet, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=color.min(), vmax=color.max())) 
    sm._A = []
    plt.colorbar(sm)

    plt.show()
```

And so far, so good; but I'm having trouble aligning the projected plot on the grid on the chart area:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lUxe.jpg)

[image]

The yellow dots should be on the value 2 on the grid, for example. 
Playing around with the zs value on the plots, I can align them, but when I change the values, the grid's scale moves and the plots are not aligned again.

Also, I can't for the life of me push the red dots to the back of the chart.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you tell what you mean by "push the red dots to the back of the chart". Do you mean on the `x-z` plane? And the yellow points are indeed at `y=2`. The reason it looks like they are not is purely an artifact of the view angle. If you rotate the plot, you will see that the points are indeed at `y=2`

Comment: Yeah, on the x-z plane. I see what you mean...I'm comparing this graph with another one from a simulation software where the dots are indeed on the grid line of y=2, so I thought that there was something that I needed to adjust.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the following lines in your code and it makes it look like you want. You can adjust the `ylim` as per your desired aesthetics

```
ax.plot(x, z, 'r+', zdir='y', zs=2.5 ,marker= 'o', alpha=0.05)
ax.plot(x, y, 'y+', zdir='z', zs=0, marker= 'o', alpha=0.05)

ax.set_ylim(0, 2.5) 
ax.set_zlim(0, 600)
```

**Output**

[image]